# Download files into system in which we are executing an API

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I need to download files from third party APIs.

I have written an API in my application which calls third party APIs and downloads files. I am able to download the files and unzip it successfully. These files are getting downloaded into tomcat server where the code is deployed when i hit my API.

But I would like to get those files downloaded into the system in which i am executing my API. Suppose, if i deploy that code into test environment  server and execute my API using curl command from my local system, then files should get downloaded into my local system. Is there anyway I can achieve this in Java?

```
public class SnapshotFilesServiceImplCopy {

public static final ILogger LOGGER = FWLogFactory.getLogger();

private RestTemplate mxRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();


public void listSnapShotFiles(String diId, String snapshotGuid) {

    LOGGER.debug("Entry - SnapshotFilesServiceImpl: FI=" + diId + " snapshotGuid=" + snapshotGuid);
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = null;
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(CommonUtil.getReportingAPIHeaders());
    String resourceURL = "files_url";
    try {
        responseEntity = mxRestTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    } catch (RestClientException re) {
        if (re instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
            //TO be handled
        }
    }

    String data = (String) responseEntity.getBody();

    try {
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(data);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("accounts");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            String accountFileURL = (String) jsonArray.get(i);
            downloadAccountsData(diId, accountFileURL);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void downloadAccountsData(String diId, String accountsURL) {

    LOGGER.debug("Entry - SnapshotFilesServiceImpl: FI=" + diId + " snapshotGuid=" + accountsURL);
    ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = null;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", "application/vnd.mx.logs.v1+json");
    headers.set("API-KEY", "key");

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(CommonUtil.getReportingAPIHeaders());
    String resourceURL = accountsURL;
    try {
        responseEntity = mxRestTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);
    } catch (RestClientException re) {
        if (re instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
            //To be handled
        }
    }
    Date date = new Date();
    String fileName = RenumberingConstants.SNAPSHOT_FILE_ACCOUNTS + date.getTime();
    try {


        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".gz");

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream());
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName + ".gz");
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".avro");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        //close resources
        fos.close();
        gis.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File file = new File(fileName + ".gz");
    boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
    if (isDeleted)
        System.out.println("File has been deleted successfully.." + fileName + ".gz");
    else
        System.out.println("Could not delete the file.." + fileName + ".gz");

  }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the scope of your question to the minimum. If I understand you correctly, you have an application that is deployed on some "server", and when you trigger something from your local machine, the "server" downloads files onto this "server". Now you want to extend this "server" to offer you these files to download them onto your local machine. Please try to update your question accordingly and show what you have tried so far. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the file received from third party API in one file (`new File()`) object, and then can save that file object at desired location. I need to see the code snippet which downloads the file from third party API to answer precisely.

What you are doing is saving the file in server (as Java program in tomcat cannot access client machine) and not returning it to the client which is calling your API. You need to open another output stream, and return the file data to client machine using that stream. You can refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file) tutorial on how to download a file using streams.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose, if i deploy that code into QA environment and execute my API using curl command from my local system, then files should get downloaded into my local system. Is there anyway I can achieve this in Java?

It is only achievable in Java (or any language) if the file or files are returned as the HTTP response to the request that you made using `curl`.

Or ... I suppose ... if you set up an HTTP server on your local system and the QA system "delivered" the files (in effect, a reverse upload!) by making an HTTP request (API call) the HTTP server.